# In a synchrotron, do the charged particles within the beam lose mass (or another type of energy) after radiation has been produced?

Tags: energy, accelerator-physics, synchrotron-radiation

I've been researching accelerators and synchrotrons and am a bit confused on what happens to the particles within the storage ring once radiation has been produced.
Do they keep circling the ring, do they loose mass or kinetic energy, or does something else entirely happen?

Also, synchrotrons are capable of producing a range of different radiations, but how are these different radiations produced? What differs in the process?

Answer (score 0):

Masses of particles at the quantum level are invariant, the length of the [four vector.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) The energy to the particles is supplied by magnets..

> [The final stages of acceleration](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/synch.html) in the major accelerator facilities are usually synchrotrons. They consist of large circular devices where charged particles travel in evacuated pipes under the influence of magnets which are positioned around the circumference of the circle. Acceleration is achieved by the application of radio frequency electric fields at RF cavities along the circumference of the ring. The magnetic fields must be increased synchronously with the acceleration in order to keep the particles on the constant radius path. Such accelerators can be used with protons or electrons, and even with heavier positive ions.

please read the ling for more details.